# Angular HttpInterceptor - How to reference tokens (string var) before sending to server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, local-storage, jwt

I'm trying to find a simple way to pass one of three kind of tokens (JWT, Facebook SDK and Google SDK) from `AuthInterceptor` to my backend server.
When user is authenticated, a token is stored on localStorage: that may be JWT token, FB token or Google Token.

Here is `AuthInterceptor`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;
        const tokenFB = 'FB ' + localStorage.getItem('tokenFB') || null;
        const tokenG = 'G ' + localStorage.getItem('tokenG') || null;
        if (token || tokenFB || tokenG) {
            const authToken = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + (token ? token : '') + (tokenFB ? tokenFB : '') +
                (tokenG ? tokenG : ''))
            });
            return next.handle(authToken);
        } else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }

}
```

Originally it worked fine just with localStorage `token`, but now i'm trying to pass different kinds of token, and the token needs something to reference them on server side (like `FB` and `G` after `BEARER`).

Here is my Node.js class `auth.js` that catches the token from a request:

```js
// auth.js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.headers.authorization);
        // this works for JWT
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        // need to know token type: JWT, Facebook (FB) or Google (G)
        // const tokenFB = ?
        // const tokenG = ?
        // JWT Token
        const decodedToken = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_Key);
        // FB and Google Methods to decode
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).send('Auth Failed.');
    }
};
```

I'm recovering the `token` value on `auth.js`, but I need to know the token type (JWT Token, Facebook or Google Token) because there is different methods for decoding tokens.

Comment: JSON web tokens contain readable data, can't you find the provider's pattern in every token?

Comment: I think I misread and the FB and Google tokens are not JWT. If this is the case, then you could add a custom header beginning with `X-` for example `X-Auth-Provider` and put a key string inside it

Comment: The `X-` stands for custom header, it ensures no collision with a real HTTP header and no interpretation from the browser or the backend

Comment: Yeah FB and Google tokens are provided from social SDK... so i can add an extra custom header like `X-Auth-Provider` and call it `req.headers.x-auth-provider` ?

Comment: Yeah, this is the best solution since it would be hard and quite dirty to recognize tokens based on some pattern

Comment: Okay added a custom header `const authToken = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers
                .set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + Token.token)
                .set('X-Auth-Provider', Token.provider)
            });` and now it works. Thanks for the help.